# I am trying to automate basics commands using python but ssh to a firewall through a console server is not successful. The terminal is getting hanged

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.1.1.1',port=3014,username='console',password='console')
```

After I I connect to the console server, I need to login to my firewall. I need to hit enter and then a login prompt appears followed by the password prompt.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('\n')
stdin.write('admin')
stdin.write('\n')
stdin.flush()
stdin.write('password')
stdin.write('\n')
stdin.flush()
stdin.write('show version')
output = stdout.readlines()
print( '\n'.join(output))
```